# Indexing the second element to the end of an array?

Tags: c, arrays

I have an array `args` defined as follows :

```
char *args[MAX_LINE/+1];    /* MAX_LINE = 80 */
```

I want to pass `args[0]` to `execvp` and the rest of the array as the second parameter:

```
execvp(args[0], args[1-x]);
```

I tried multiples things. Namely :

```
execvp(args[0], args+MAX_LINE);    /* args+MAX_LINE should point to the second element of the array (?) */
```

and writing an extra function which would remove the first element of the array by shifting all the elements by one to the left :

```
void getOpts(char *opts[])
{
 int i = 0;    /* index used in the for loop */

 for(i=0;opts[i] != NULL;i++)
   opts[i] = opts[i+1];
 }
```

This solution worked, but partially. The problem is the second element can sometimes be `NULL`. And the system returns an error when `execvp` is invoked.

Is there an easy way to index the second element to the end of an array?

Comment: Um, is that divide on purpose?  (MAX_LINE/+1).  That's just MAX_LINE.

Comment: Using pointer arithmetics: `args+1` or bracket notation: `&args[1]` are the ways to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, `args` is an array that decays to a pointer to the first element of the array, so `args+1` points to the second element. So your code should be:

```
execvp(args[0], args+1);
```

Comment: Or, if you find it easier to think about, execvp(args[0], &args[1]).

Comment: Of course! This is so obvious, why didn't I think about that? Thanks!